# Forçar ordem de execução Swift 3/Xcode 8 - Threads

Tags: ios, swift, thread, xcode, multithreading

Olá, sou novo em swift e essa semana me deparei com um problema que já está me fazendo arrancar os cabelos!
O que acontece é o seguinte, dividi em minha aplicação em várias classes para deixar meu código mais "ajeitado" e nessa onda decidi dividir algumas funções em classes pelo projeto, mas até ai tudo bem.
O problema é como o Swift trata as filas de execução, deixando para segundo plano tudo que não está na minha ViewController, o que está me atrapalhando.
Vou mostrar um pouco do código para que vocês estendam melhor o que estou dizendo

A função do botão do meu ViewController:

```
    @IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //Eis a linha que o swift "pula"
    let dadosAlunoWS = FadbaWS.buscaAluno(matricula: MatriculaTbox.text!, senha: SenhaTbox.text!, token: "TOKEN")  

    //'dadosAlunoWS' será sempre vazio porque 'FadbaWS.buscaAluno' 
    //só é executada ao fim de 'btnLogin'

    if dadosAlunoWS.sucesso && dadosAlunoWS.usuarioEncontrado{
        print(dadosAlunoWS.nome)

    }else{ 

        //Erro na requisição
    }        
}
```

Eu conheço o conceito de paralelismo e concorrência e pesquisando pude perceber que é nativo do Swift dar prioridade a interface, o que torna tudo fluído, mas meu problema é que minha função 'FadbaWS.buscaAluno' nunca é executada e assim nunca retorna um valor válido.
Como dar prioridade para que meu código só prossiga depois de executar essa função?
Como lidar com o DispatchQueue em Swift?
Desde já, grato!

Comment: Você vai precisar usar um callback como parâmetro no seu método _buscaAluno_. Sugiro dar uma pesquisa sobre callback no Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver meu problema, usei um CompletionHandler

```
       self.FadbaWS.buscaAluno(matricula: MatriculaTbox.text!, senha: SenhaTbox.text!, token: "TOKEN", complete:{ resultado in

      if resultado.2 && resultado.3{
        print(resultado.0)
      }else 
        //Error on request
      }
   })
```

No meu caso, eu precisava de alguns parametros, então o fiz assim:

```
    func buscaAluno(matricula: String, senha: String, token: String, complete: @escaping (_ nome: String?, _ login: String?, _ sucesso:Bool, _ userok:Bool) -> Void) {

    complete("Wender", "1234", true, true)

  }
}
```

Quando minha função 'buscaAluno' for finalizada, a função 'complete' é executada